# Javascript wait for function with async/await to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, html-datalist

I know it was asked before plenty of times but for the life of me I can't figure out the proper way to make it work. I am working on NodeJS project. I need to display a certain value in the  based on query results, but also have that  populated with all available options. My function to initially populate  works properly.

```
async function fillDatalist(){
   await  $('#html_placeholder').load('/path/to/some.html', function() {
      getValues_for_Datalist() 
    });
}
```

After I get specific values from database, i need to display it.

```
async function display_value_from_DB (value_string) {
   await fillDatalist()
   document.getEleemntbyID(datalist_id).value = value_string
}
```

I get en error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Which i believe is that due to the fact that function fillDatalist did not complete.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What database are you using

Comment: `load()` doesn't return a promise so there is nothing to `await`

Comment: @lfaruki MySQL. Everything database related works as expected